# fragment not being inflated

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'am trying to load map fragment from an activity.

code for activity:

```java
package com.example.project;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Adapter;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class VehicleListActivity extends ListActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list_viewer);

        ListView list = getListView();
        ListAdapter adapter = new ListAdapter(getApplicationContext());

        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        list.setItemsCanFocus(true);

        list.setOnItemClickListener
        (
                new OnItemClickListener()
                {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                            int arg2, long arg3) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "you hav clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        Adapter adapter = arg0.getAdapter();
                        String vehicleNumber = ((VehicleDetails) adapter.getItem(arg2)).getVehicleNumber();
                        double latitude = ((VehicleDetails) adapter.getItem(arg2)).getLatitude();
                        double longitude = ((VehicleDetails) adapter.getItem(arg2)).getLongitude();

                        Bundle data = new Bundle();
                        data.putString("VEHICLE_No", vehicleNumber);
                        data.putDouble("LATITUDE", latitude);
                        data.putDouble("LONGITUDE", longitude);

                        MapLoaderFragment map = new MapLoaderFragment();
                        map.setArguments(data);

                    }

                }
        );
    }

}
```

Code for fragment class:

```html
package com.example.project;

import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class MapLoaderFragment extends Fragment {
 
 MapView mapView;
 GoogleMap map;
 
 public MapLoaderFragment()
 {
 }
 
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
 {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 }

 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
   Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  
  String vehicleNumber = getArguments().getString("VEHICLE_NO");
  double latitude = getArguments().getDouble("LATITUDE");
  double longitude = getArguments().getDouble("LONGITUDE");
  
  View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_fragment, container, false);
  
  mapView = (MapView) view.findViewById(R.id.map);
  mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  
  map = mapView.getMap();
  
  try {
   MapsInitializer.initialize(this.getActivity());
  } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
  
  LatLng position = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
  Marker marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions());
  marker.setTitle(vehicleNumber);
  marker.setPosition(position);
  marker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.car));
  
  CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(
    position).zoom(15).build();
  map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
  
  return view;
 }

 @Override
 public void onDestroy() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  mapView.onDestroy();
  super.onDestroy();
 }

 @Override
 public void onResume() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  mapView.onResume();
  super.onResume();
 }

}
```

This is what I've done so far. In main activity i'am loading list, adding on click listener to list. From the on click i'am trying to load the map by sending the latitude longitude and vehicle number.

Code for MainActivity.xml:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Code for Map Fragment:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>    
<fragment
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

Comment: where you replace or insert your `MapLoaderFragment`?

Comment: My main thinking behind the code was If I click on any list item from MainActivity then a map should load with the location that was sent with the puString() method. Am i doing wrong please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Mainly there are 2 ways to use a fragment into an Activity.

> Static: Declare the fragment inside the activity's layout file.

Or

> Dynamic: programmatically add the fragment to an existing.

In your code seems that you are not insert the fragment programmatically, then your problem will be in your xml layout.

Basic examples here: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Answer (score 1):

You are not placing your `MapLoaderFragment` to any fragment container. Normally you would have a container in your XML layout file that will hold the fragment, then in the calling activity you'll have

```
MapLoaderFragment map = new MapLoaderFragment();
map.setArguments(data);
...
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
fm.beginTransaction()
.add(container, map)
.commit();
```